# Android webview does not work, please help

Tags: android

I tried a webview to display a web page, and I faced a big problem that caused my application stop unexpectedly. I tried many times but it showed the same error.

The error is "The webview app stop unexpectedly (process net.webview)..."

My Java code:

```
Code:
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyWebView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

My XML layout:

```
Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

My manifest file:

```
Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.WebView"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".WebView"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of your activity in the manifest is wrong. It should be:

```
   <activity android:name=".MyWebView"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my lifesaver. I spent a day for it. Have a nice holiday.

Comment: You are welcome. If it answers your question/problem, please accept this answer by ticking the green tick sign on the left side (i think).